# Emojis are missing in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm building a chat web app and I'm using `asp.net core` with `Blazor`.
I have created a component which contains :

`<input @bind="_Msg" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a Message..."/>`

and `_Msg` is just a string property.

The problem is whenever I insert any emojis in input ,like  ,it doesn't transfer to `_Msg`. for expmple:
I put **Test123** in input but `_Msg` value is **Test123**

Any idea?

Comment: Never used blazor, but would you need to specify on the input what sort of charset it should accept? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp

Comment: There is nothiing you need to do to handle emojis as demonstrated here : https://blazorfiddle.com/s/t5k2gr9m   The most likely problem you have is the way you are checking the string to see if it has emojis in it...

Comment: Thank you @MisterMagoo. The real problem was about the javascript code which put emojis inside `<input>`. I wrote about the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929649/changing-an-input-value-in-blazor-by-javascript-doesnt-change-its-binded-prope