# Changing an Input value in Blazor by javascript doesn't change it's binded property value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm building a website using `app.net core 3.1` with `blazor`.
In one of my components I have :

`<input @bind="Message" type="text" id="input-message"/>`

`Message` is just a string property.

and I have javascript:

`document.getElementById('input-message').value = 'some text';`

The problem is after running the above js, `<input>` value changes but `Message` value doesn't, and of course if I type or paste something inside `<input>` , `Message` value changes too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently changing `<input>` value or any other changes in DOM by javascript doesn't change State, so blazor won't re-render the component. Even calling `StateHasChanged();` manually in your razor page won't work.

To get this done, you just have to trigger the same DOM events that occur if the user modifies the `<input>` normally, just like below:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('input-message');
myElement.value = 'some text';
var event = new Event('change');
myElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Is this solution still working? I have done exactly the same in my code, the input value is updating, but not the bounded value in blazor, the component does not re-render.

Comment: It's still working

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works with hidden input elements too.

Comment: Didn't work for me on a InputTextArea

Comment: It did work when I quit using InputTextArea and InputText.  This worked using .net 7:  `<input @bind:event="onchange" @bind:get="userTagsStr" @bind:set="OnTagChange"  class="form-control" id="usertags" />` example found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't change the input value directly in javascript, what you should do is call a c# function that updates the value and then it will update the javascript.

Instead of doing

```
document.getElementById('input-message').value = 'some text';
```

You should do something like

```
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('UpdateMessageValue', 'some text');
```

Where you have

```
public void UpdateMessageValue(string value){
    Message = value;
}
```

And because you are using `bind` in the input, the value of `document.getElementById('input-message').value` will be changed, and the value in the c# will also be changed.

This answer isn't complete, I'm passing you the idea on how to do it and not the correct code to solve your case, but if you want more information on how to do it, you can take a look at [Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the third-party lib script that is modifying your input field you can always use the following solution. 
The concept is the following:
After rendering the component we call JS to start intercepting the all input fields value setters, then we get our callback in Blazor from JS. Blazor then dispatches to appropriate field.

Fields example:

```
    <div class="input-group input-daterange" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
    <input type="text" 
           id="InputDateFrom" 
           @bind="InputDateFrom" 
           class="form-control text-center" placeholder="От">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    <input type="text" 
           id="InputDateTo" 
           @bind="InputDateTo" 
           class="form-control text-center" placeholder="До">
</div>
```

JS:

```
    function WatchInputFields(callbackChangedName, dotnetRef) {
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");
var originalSet = descriptor.set;

// define our own setter
descriptor.set = function (val) {

    console.log("Value set", this, val);
    originalSet.apply(this, arguments);

    dotnetRef.invokeMethodAsync(callbackChangedName, this.id, this.value);
}

Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value", descriptor); }
```

BLAZOR: 
Inside `OnAfterRenderAsync` call `InitInputFieldsToTrackOnce` on first rendering (or second one in case of server with prerendering):

```
   private async Task InitInputFieldsToTrackOnce()
    {

        _objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);

        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync(
            "WatchInputFields",
            "OnInputFieldChanged",
            _objRef);

        WatchInputField("InputDateFrom", (value) => { _InputDateFrom = value; Console.WriteLine($"Setting FROM to {value}"); });
        WatchInputField("InputDateTo", (value) => { _InputDateTo = value; ; Console.WriteLine($"Setting TO to {value}"); });

    }

    void WatchInputField(string id, Action<string> onChanged)
    {
        InputFieldChanges.TryAdd(id, onChanged);
    }


    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<string>> InputFieldChanges { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<string>>();

    private DotNetObjectReference<ShopDesk> _objRef;

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task OnInputFieldChanged(string id, string value)
    {
        var ok = InputFieldChanges.TryGetValue(id, out Action<string> action);
        if (ok)
            action(value);
    }
```

And dispose `_objRef` when disposing your component.