# Bounded value not updated when modified by JsInterop

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've been trying to implement a custom keyboard solution for one of my projects, so I created a custom component for this. Each time a key is pressed on this component, a javascript function is called and receives the id of the input that has currently the focus.

```
function WriteInput(elementId, letter) {
var myElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
myElement.value = letter.toLowerCase();
myElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
return true;
}
```

The jsInterop :

```
    public async Task<bool> WriteInput(string elementId, string letter)
    {
        return await _js.InvokeAsync<bool>("WriteInput", elementId, letter);
    }
```

The KeyBoard Component logic (Keyboard.Id is a value retrieved from a state container) :

```
private async void OnClick(string letter)
    {
        await _FocusService.WriteInput(KeyBoard.Id, letter);
    }
```

The html :

```
<input @bind-Value="ViewModel.Username" OnFocus='()=>KeyBoard.Id="loginusername"' Id="loginusername"  />
```

The issue here is that I can see the letters in the input, but the ViewModel.Username is not updated even if the change event is thrown, what am I missing here, I have the same code as in here and apparently it is working : [Changing an Input value in Blazor by javascript doesn't change it's binded property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929649/changing-an-input-value-in-blazor-by-javascript-doesnt-change-its-binded-prope)

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is this? `OnFocus='()=>KeyBoard.Id="loginusername"'` - a typo maybe? Did you mean to have the C# directive `@onfocus` or did you really want inline JS?

Comment: When you click into the input, then click on your custom keyboard, you will get a `change` event against the input which will update the bound property (and it will re-render which will update the input's value), and a `click` event on the keyboard, which also updates and fires a `change` event on the input. How are you testing the bound value has been updated? and how are you synchronising all these events?

Comment: I test if the bounded value has been updated by just setting a <h1>@bindedValue</h1> to see if it's updating when I'm typing on my custom keyboard event (it's not, the only value being updated is the value in the input itself but not the value bounded to this input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the code you provided down to a bare bones working model that shows the bind value being updated.  The JS is in site.js which is referenced in _Host.cshtml.

```
@page "/"
<h3>SoftKeyboard</h3>
<div class="m-1 p-2">
    First Name: <input @bind-value="_model.FirstName" id="FirstNameField" />
</div>
<div class="m-1 p-2">
    Surname: <input @bind-value="_model.Surname" id="SurnameField" />
</div>
<div class="m-1 p-2">
    UserName: <input @bind-value="_model.UserName" id="UserNameField" />
</div>

<div class="m-1 p-2">
   Focus Control:  <select @onchange="FieldSelector">
        <option value="FirstNameField">First Name</option>
        <option value="SurnameField">Surname</option>
        <option value="UserNameField">User Name</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="m-1 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark ms-1" @onclick="((e) => SoftClick('A'))">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark ms-1" @onclick="((e) => SoftClick('S'))">S</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark ms-1" @onclick="((e) => SoftClick('D'))">D</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark ms-1" @onclick="((e) => SoftClick('F'))">F</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark ms-1" @onclick="((e) => SoftClick('K'))">K</button>
</div>

<div class="m-1 p-2">
    <div>First Name: @_model.FirstName</div>
    <div>Surname: @_model.Surname</div>
    <div>User Name: @_model.UserName</div>
</div>

@code {

    [Inject] IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }

    async void SoftClick(char key)
    {
        await _js.InvokeAsync<bool>("WriteInput", selectedField, key);
    }

    void FieldSelector(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedField = e.Value.ToString();
    }

    private string selectedField = "FirstNameField";

    public class Model
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    Model _model = new Model();
}
```

Comment: Actually I need JsInterop in this case, because I want to allow my keyboard component to modify the input focused, so my guess was to assign an Id to the state container each time an input is focused, and then modify this input using the Id and javascript, if this is possible in blazor I'm open to it but I did not find anything.

Comment: Question.  In what you have shown so far you are modifying the input to lower case. So when you say you want to modify the input focused, I'm assuming you are saying you don't want the transformation fixed to a single input/value.  I've updated my answer to show how to use a simple control to "manage" keyboard input.

Comment: But with your example, the input is directly modified by the input of the user, the issue is that I cannot use OnInput since the keyboard component is a blazor component (= when you click on my keyboard, it is the same as I would click on any button, but here the button has a value=>>the letter that was clicked on). So I cannot link the onInput with the keyboard event if you see what I mean, that's why, I need to be able to modify the input that has the current focus with the event that was raised on the keyboard

Comment: Now I've got you.  Can you share a bit more code?  I'm assuming your keyboard control is some sort of soft keyboard.  how do you change focus?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, week-end time ! So basically I have a state container holding the id of the input I want to be modified with the keyboard and on each Input I call on focus like <input id="thisid" @onfocus="()=>{KeyBoardStateContainer.Id="thisid"; KeyBoardStateContainer.Visible=true;} />and setting also the visible state of the keyboard to true. For the keyboard, I load a json file representing the layout of the keyboard and then

Comment: I do : @foreach (string character in row.characters)
    {
     
       <div class="keyboard-letter" @onclick="() => OnClick(character)">@character</div>
       break;
    } and the onclick method here is calling the WriteInput method I shared above

Comment: My suggestion is to try `ElementReference` rather than `id`, though I suspect your problem is that the blazor event is not being fired when you dispatch that change event.

Comment: Wild goose chase.  See my totally revised answer for a very bare bones working version of your code.